# gcc file not found issue

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to compile a simple little test program. and I'm getting errors:

```
MacBook-Air:Untitled user$ ls
main.c      makefile    utils.c     utils.h
MacBook-Air:Untitled user$ make
avr-gcc -I.  -g -mmcu=atmega640 -Os -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -funsigned-bitfields -funsigned-char -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wa,-ahlms=main.lst -c main.c -o main.o
make: avr-gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
MacBook-Air:Untitled user$
```

What file is gcc complaining about? `main.c` does exist in the same directory as the makefile so I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the C file it can't find, it's the C compiler (avr-gcc).  Is it defined in the makefile?  E.g. `CC=avr-gcc` ?  You could try replacing that with `CC=gcc`

Comment: replacing gcc-avr with gcc and removing all the flags for avr, it does compile. What file is it what avr-gcc can't find?

Comment: The problem is the makefile is trying to use a compiler called avr-gcc, which you don't have installed.

Comment: ugh, it is a pathing issue... :-/ have to escape the space.